# Train Mahout to interpret data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mahout

I have a set of questions which belong to a Customer Satisfaction Survey. The answers of users are in the form of a CSV file. Based on the answers to the questions, boolean values of 0 and 1 are assigned to each user's response depicting bad and good experience respectively.

My task is use Mahout to train a model with a set of questions such that it is able to analyse and answer questions fed to it later. And since the input data is huge, I've got to use MapReduce in conjunction with it.

Unfortunately, I am unable to make the head and tail of Mahout and have no idea how to proceed. Can someone please guide me on which model I should train and how should I go about doing it?

P. S. I have no knowledge of machine learning. So please try to explain the jargon, if used.

Comment: I lost you at the part where you say you want to be able to answer questions automatically. Would these questions be the same as in the training set? What would consist a good answer? Or did I misunderstand and you're simply trying to classify future answers as either 0 or 1?

Comment: Through some analysis, I'll be classifying a set of answered questions (say 1000) as 0 or 1. Then the rest of the set of answered questions (say 100k) I'll want to classify them as 0 or 1 using Mahout as it would be difficult doing manually.

Comment: I would suggest using around 70-80% of your data for training, and the rest to test it. Using only 1k for training when you have more than 100k items won't probably make accurate precisions. As a general rule of thumb, the more data you have for training, the better your algorithm will perform, so if you have the data you should use as much as possible for training. Also if you have only 100k items, not sure if you really need to do it in Hadoop, just something like Weka should do just fine.

Comment: These are sample records, 1k and 100k. The main data would be way larger. If I want to use Hadoop and Mahout, how do I proceed?